# How to read string array column in Hbase

Tags: hbase

How to read and write a `hbase` column which is of type `String[]` ?

e.g. To write a string array myArray to `hbase` column we can do that like this:

```
Put put = new Put("r1".getBytes)

byte[] colValue1 = myArray.toString.getBytes();

put.addColumn("columnFamily".getBytes, "c1".getBytes, colValue1);
```

Now how I can is read this?
Is there any better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This way is not true to the getting byte array from the string array. If you are use toString directly, when you want to get it you cannot get the string array. You can use those methods to string array to byte array and byte array to string array.

```
  private def byteArrayToStringArray(byteStrings: Array[Array[Byte]]) = {
    val data = new Array[String](byteStrings.length)

    for(i <- 0.to(byteStrings.length)) {
      data(i) = new String(byteStrings(i), Charset.defaultCharset)
    }
    data
  }


  private def stringArrayToByteArray(strings: Array[String]) = {
    val data = new Array[Array[Byte]](strings.length)
    for (i <- 0.to(strings.length)) {
      val string = strings(i)
        data(i) = string.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset)
    }
    data
  }
```